# Making Orchard Services Available in Web Forms: Disable Disposing Orchard Services IOrchardService?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

After Adding a New Module to the Orchard Solution in VS 2013, In the Home Controller's Index method, Iam saving the IOrchardServices in Session as:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IOrchardServices Services { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IOrchardServices services)
    {
        Services = services;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
           Session["OrchardCMServices"] = Services;
           return Redirect("/OrchardLocal/modules/HelloWorld/default.aspx");
    }
```

After storing the Orchard Services in Session,Redirection to  WebForms Page: `default.aspx`  is done. This does redirects successfully.

The Problem is that when I access the above Session["OrchardCMServices"] in my ASPX page, the ContentManager is disposed and I cannot query using GET methods. The Error is: Object Disposed

How can I Disable/Prevent the Disposing of the Session Objects while Redirecting from MVC to Asp.NET ? I didn't find any `modules` settings in `web.config` of the MVC App.

***Is there any way to make the Orchard Services ( ContentManager) available on Web Forms ?*** 
[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like people know how to make Orchard compatible with Webforms. Perhaps if you update the question describing what your end goal is there might be another way to present the data to this external page?

Comment: @rtpHarry : Thank you for the response and suggestions. Yes there are ways to present data to External page Like Querying the SQL CE database directly in my Web Forms Applications. That was one way to go.

But, since we were using ORCHARD CMS, my only goal was to check if  there is a way to make the Orchard Services available to Web Forms Page too

Comment: I'm just doing some work on the OrchardDocs folder and [stumbled across this article](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation#RenderingWebFormsViews). Its incomplete and targeted at Orchard v0.5 but I thought of this thread and thought I would at least post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services in Orchard have different scopes depending on their purpose. IOrchardServices has a lifetime scope of request, so it will be destroyed at the end of the request.

> Request: a dependency instance is created for each new HTTP request and is destroyed once the request has been processed. Use this by deriving your interface from IDependency. The object should be reasonably cheap to create.
>   http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/How-Orchard-works

And you can see that IOrchardServices is an IDependency.

```
public interface IOrchardServices : IDependency {...
```

So you shouldn't try to store the service in the current session. If you need to access the service in a view you can resolve it using the work context like this:

```
var orchardServices = WorkContext.Resolve<IOrchardServices>();
```

Or if your module has a controller that is rendering the page you can inject the dependency as normal.

Comment: Hmm... I see the point. So, What if I want to access the OrchardService in one of my WEB FORMS ( .aspx) pages actually and NOT in any MVC views. Is there a way to do this ? The ASPX pages are present in the Sample HelloWorld Module I created as documented in Orchard. As you can see in the INDEX() method of Controller, I Just redirected to the ASPX page and in the ASPX page I tried reading back the Session value, where i then Query again the Content Manager as: int itemID = 12; ContentItem iTem = this.Services.ContentManager.Get(itemID);. This is the line which throws the Error in ASPX page –

Comment: I spent some more time looking into this and couldn't find a way to access any dependencies inside of a web form. Orchard does a lot of custom stuff to inject the dependencies in a view that just might not be possible to use in a web form page.

Comment: Thanks for your time on finding out a way to make the Orchard Services available on Web Forms. Even I myself now concluded the same that its nearly impossible to make these Orchard Services available in Web Forms page. Since there were few pages in Web Forms that Required Data, so for the Time Being, we are Querying those Tables separately using the Ado.NET way.... Do let me know if you know some other better alternate ways....